# Using result from Test 1 to start Test 2

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I want to run 2 tests:

1. Step 1 - open google, Step 2 - type in a search item, Step 3 - print out first entry
2. Step 1 - user URL from Step 3 in Test 1, Step 2 - click url, Step 3 - verify a tag line

I cannot figure out how to use the URL from Test 1 to start my second Test

```
package test;

import cucumber.annotation.en.Given;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then;
import cucumber.annotation.en.When;
import cucumber.annotation.en.And;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class MyTest {

private WebDriver driver;
private Object ExpectedConditions;
private Object MyTestHomePage;

@Given("I have a opened google in a web browser")
public void MyTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Driver/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
}

@When("I enter MyTest in search box")
public void TruNarrative_search() {
    WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchButton.sendKeys("mysearchitem");
    searchButton.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}

@Then("I can identify MyTest as first entry")
public void MyTest_result() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("MycssSelector"));
    for (WebElement webElement : findElements) {
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    }
}

public class MyTest2 {
    @Given("I have found the MyTest webpage via google")
    public void TMyTest_found() {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("MycssSelector"));
    }


    @When("I click on the link")
    public void MyTest_click() {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("mycssSelector")).click();
    }

    @Then("I can identify the strap line “Blah Blah Blah.” Is found on the page")
    public void TruNarrative_tag() {
        WebElement tagLine = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4.bigger[text()='Blah Blah Blah.']"));
        if (tagLine.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Element found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: FWIW: sharing state between tests is considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Cucumber will not let you do that, as each Scenario should start "fresh" and be independent of the others.

While I understand that you might want to use the result of one test as the starting point for another, we highly recommend having independent tests.
The reason is that if your first test should fail for any reason, your second test will automatically also fail (as there is no input from the first test). 
This will make it harder and more time consuming to analyse failures, especially as your test suite grows.

Instead, consider starting the second test with the URL you expect, opening it and verifying the tagline.

This way, both tests are testing different things and will fail for different reasons.